# Assembler. Чтение из файла

Tags: ассемблер

Есть следующее задание:
Файл содержит сведения о товарах, находящихся на складе: наименование, объем партии,
дата поступления на склад, стоимость единицы товара. Разработать программу поиска
характеристик товара по его наименования и запись их в отдельный файл, имя которого
будет характеризоваться наименованием товара.
Написала вот такой код в ассемблере, но он не хочет открывать файл, знающие подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

```
.model small
.data
handle  dw 0; хэндл открытого файла
rbuff   db 8 dup(0); Сюда читается символ из файла
inp db 'Input file name: $'
msg2    db 13, 10, 'Input output file name: $'
msg1    db 13, 10, 'Input product name: $'
msg3    db 13, 10, 'Done!$'
msg4    db 13, 10, 'Not found!$'
buf db 13, 14 dup(0); принимает строку, введенную с клавиатуры
e   db 13, 10, 'Error!$'
strf    db 512 dup(0); строка, прочитанная из файла
naim    db 21 dup(0)
kol db 11 dup(0)
date    db 11 dup(0)
price   db 11 dup(0)
snaim   db 21, 22 dup(0); принимает строку, введенную с клавиатуры
ms1 db 'Наименование: ', 0
ms2 db 13, 10, 'Объем партии: ', 0
ms3 db 13, 10, 'Дата поступления на склад: ', 0
ms4 db 13, 10, 'Стоимость единицы товара: ', 0

.stack 256
.code
start :
mov ax, @data; Настраиваем сегментные регистры
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ah, 9; функция вывода сообщения на экран
lea dx, inp; выводимое сообщение
int 21h; выводим на экран
mov ah, 0ah; функция ввода строки с клавиатуры
mov dx, offset buf; буфер куда вводить
int 21h; пользователь вводит в текстовом виде в buf
mov bh, 0
mov bl, buf[1]; длина введенной строки
mov buf[bx + 2], byte ptr 0; добавить 0 в конец введенной строки

mov ah, 9; функция вывода сообщения на экран
lea dx, msg1; выводимое сообщение
int 21h; выводим на экран
mov ah, 0ah; функция ввода строки с клавиатуры
mov dx, offset snaim; буфер куда вводить
int 21h; пользователь вводит текст
mov bh, 0
mov bl, snaim[1]; длина введенной строки
mov snaim[bx + 2], byte ptr 0; добавить 0 в конец введенной строки

mov ax, 3d00h; функция открытия файла на чтение
lea dx, buf[2]; введенное имя файла
int 21h; попытка открыть
jnc opened; если ошибка - переход
jmp er
opened : mov handle, ax; сохранить хэндл открытого файла
lp1 : call gets; читаем строку из текста, в ах возвращается длина строки
cmp ax, -1; если длина = -1, значит достигли конца файла
jnz c1
jmp kon_file; и выход
c1 : lea si, strf
mov ax, si
call strlen; длина строки
cmp ax, 42; если длина прочитанной строки менее 42 символов
jb lp1; то пропустить эту строку
lea di, naim
mov cx, 20
rep movsb; скопировать наименование
lea si, naim
call rtrim; удалить в нем пробелы справа

lea si, strf + 20
lea di, kol
mov cx, 10
rep movsb; скопировать количество
lea si, kol
call rtrim; удалить в нем пробелы справа

lea si, strf + 30
lea di, date
mov cx, 10
rep movsb; скопировать дату

lea si, strf + 41
lea di, price
mov cx, 10
rep movsb; скопировать цену
lea si, price
call rtrim; удалить в ней пробелы справа

lea si, naim
lea di, snaim[2]
call strcmpi; сравнить введенное наименование с прочитанным из файла
jnz lp1; если не совпали, продолжить
mov ah, 9; функция вывода сообщения на экран
lea dx, msg2; выводимое сообщение
int 21h; выводим на экран
mov ah, 0ah; функция ввода строки с клавиатуры
mov dx, offset buf; буфер куда вводить
int 21h; пользователь вводит в текстовом виде в buf
mov bh, 0
mov bl, buf[1]; длина введенной строки
mov buf[bx + 2], byte ptr 0; добавить 0 в конец введенной строки
lea dx, buf[2]; адрес имени создаваемого файла
mov ah, 3ch; функция создания папки
mov cx, 0; атрибуты
int 21h; создаем файл
mov bx, ax; сохраняем хэндл файла
lea dx, ms1; вывести в файл наименование
call fputs
lea dx, naim
call fputs
lea dx, ms2; количество
call fputs
lea dx, kol
call fputs
lea dx, ms3
call fputs
lea dx, date; дату
call fputs
lea dx, ms4
call fputs
lea dx, price; и цену
call fputs
mov ah, 3eh; ф - я закрытия файла
mov bx, handle; закрытие исходного
mov ah, 9; функция вывода сообщения на экран
lea dx, msg3; выводимое сообщение
int 21h; выводим на экран
mov ah, 3eh; ф - я закрытия файла
mov bx, handle; закрытие исходного
int 21h
jmp ex; продолжить обработку файла
kon_file :
mov ah, 3eh; ф - я закрытия файла
mov bx, handle; закрытие исходного
int 21h
mov ah, 9; функция вывода сообщения на экран
lea dx, msg4; выводимое сообщение
int 21h; выводим на экран

ex : mov ah, 1; Ожидаем нажатия любой клавиши
int 21h
mov ax, 4c00h; закончить программу
int 21h
er : mov ah, 9; функция вывода сообщения на экран
lea dx, e; выводимое сообщение
int 21h; выводим на экран
jmp ex

gets    proc; функция посимвольно читает строку из файла, в ах возвращает длину прочитанной строки
push di bx cx dx; сохраняем регистры
lea di, strf; получаемая строка
@@m1:   mov ah, 3fh; ф - я чтения из файла
mov bx, handle; хэндл файла
mov cx, 1; 1 байт
lea dx, rbuff; куда читать
int 21h; читаем один символ из файла в rbuff
test ax, ax; если прочитали 0 символов, значит файл закончился
jz @@ex1; выходим
mov al, rbuff
cmp al, 0dh;; если прочитанный символ - CR
jz @@ex; заканчиваем читать строку
stosb; если нет, сохраняем его в строку
jmp @@m1; продолжаем
@@ex:   mov ah, 3fh; читаем из файла следующий символ(LF), чтобы указатель в файле был на начале следующей строки
mov bx, handle; хэндл файла
mov cx, 1; 1 байт
lea dx, rbuff; куда читать
int 21h
; Расчитываем длину прочитанной строки
@@ex3:  mov ax, di; текущий записываемый адрес
sub ax, offset strf; вычесть начало строки
jmp @@ex2; закончить
@@ex1:  cmp di, offset strf; если не прочитали ни одного байта,
jnz @@ex3
mov ax, -1; возвращаем признак окончания
@@ex2:  mov[di], byte ptr 0; добавить 0 в конец строки
pop dx cx bx di; восстанавливаем регистры
ret
gets    endp
; Преобразование символа к нижнему регистру в кодировке CP866
; на входе al - код символа
; на выходе - код символа в нижнем регистре

tolower proc
cmp al, 'A'; если символ большая
jb lex
cmp al, 'Z'; английская
jbe lo1; то преобразовать
cmp al, 0f0h; если Ё
jz lo2; то преобразовать
cmp al, 80h;
jb lex
cmp al, 90h; если A - П
jb lo1; то преобразовать
cmp al, 9fh; если Р - Я
jbe lo3; то преобразовать
ret
lo1 : add al, 20h; преобразование A - Z, А - П
lex : ret
lo2 : mov al, 0f1h; ё
ret; конец преобразования
lo3 : add al, 50h; преобразовние Р - Я
ret
tolower endp

; сравнение строк
; di - результирующая строка
; si - исходная строка
; Результатом сравнения являются флаги
strcmpi proc
push si; сохраняем регистры
push di
push ax
strcmp1 :
mov al, [si]; берем символ из первой строки
call tolower; преобразуем в нижний регистр
mov ah, al; сохарняем
inc si; следующие
inc di; символы
mov al, [di - 1]; берем символ из второй строки
call tolower; преобразуем в нижний регистр
cmp ah, al; сравниваем с очередным символом из второй строки
jnz strcmp2; если не равны - выход
cmp al, 0; если не конец слова
jnz strcmp1; продолжить сравнение
strcmp2 :
pop ax; восстанавливаем регистры
pop di
pop si
ret
strcmpi endp
; определение длины текста
; на входе ax - адрес строки
; на выходе ах - количество символов в строке
strlen proc
push bx
mov bx, ax; начало строки
xor ax, ax; кол - во символов в строке
strlp : cmp[bx], byte ptr 0; если текущий символ 0
jz strex; то закончить подсчет
inc bx; следующий символ
inc ax; увеличить кол - во символов в строке
jmp strlp; подсчитать все символы
strex : pop bx
ret
strlen endp
; удаление пробелов в конце строки
; si - исходная строка
rtrim   proc
push ax
push di
mov ax, si
call strlen; длина строки
mov di, si
add di, ax; адрес конца строки
lptr : dec di; вернуться на один символ назад
cmp di, si; цикл пока не зайдем за начало строки
jb tr1
cmp byte ptr[di], ' '; если не пробел
jnz tr1; закончить цикл
mov byte ptr[di], 0; заменить пробел на 0
jmp lptr; продолжить
tr1 : pop di
pop ax
ret
rtrim endp
; ds:dx - адрес строки
; bx - дескриптор
; вывод строки на экран или в файл
fputs   proc
push cx
push ax; сохраняем регистры
; узнать длину выводимой строки
mov ax, dx; начало строки
call strlen
mov cx, ax; длина выводимой строки
mov ah, 40h; ф - я записи
int 21h; вывести в файл
pop ax; восстановить регистры
pop cx
ret
fputs endp
end start
```

Comment: дык, посмотри, какой код ошибки (в `AX` после `int 21h`)…

Comment: Я поставил минус за вопрос, надеюсь другие участники поступят также. Причина? Не надо "вываливать" весь свой код, интернет не твоя личная армия.